# RESTful URL for the properties of an entity (How to)

Tags: xml, json, url, rest, relational-database

I am designing some restful urls, but I am undecided on how to retrieve an entity of my domain. 
At a lower level I have a database with many-to-many and one-to- many  relationships. 
Let's suppose that the entities are Companies, Groups and Users.
The relationship between Companies and Groups is one-to-many (foreign key in Groups), the same between Companies and Users.
While, between Groups and Users the relationship is many-to-may.

My knowledge of restful API tells that I should build urls like:

- `http://mywebsite.com/company/`, `http://mywebsite.com/company/1/users/`,
  `http://mywebsite.com/company/1/groups/` for the post (creation of a new entity) and get methods;
- `http://mywebsite.com/company/1`, `http://mywebsite.com/company/1/users/1`,
  `http://mywebsite.com/company/1/groups/1` for the put (update), delete and get methods;
- `http://mywebsite.com/company/1/users/1/groups/` for the post (add new associations) and get method.

Now, my problem is how to read(get), (and eventually update(put), or change the company (post)) from a user or a group.
Basically there are 3 options:

1. `http://mywebsite.com/company/1/users/1/company` and provide the same json and xml as `http://mywebsite.com/company/1` and denying repetitive urls like `http://mywebsite.com/company/1/users/1/company/1/users`..
2. nest inside the json and xml of a user description (or of a group) the json and xml of his company, the nested part will be almost the same as  `http://mywebsite.com/company/1`.
   But this option implies at each request of a user (or a group)a join between 2 tables, even if I am interested in to know the first name only of a user;
3. provide the foreign key value only (identifier of the company) in the json and xml of the users and groups.

What is the best option for you? Why?

Answer (score 0):

I would opt for flatter URLs and operations. Concretely:

---

## Read operations

- `GET /company?id={id}`

  - Gets the company with the given `id`
- `GET /company/group?id={id}`

  - Gets the groups associated with the company with the given `id`
  - Add additional query parameters for pagination (if appropriate)
- `GET /company/user?id={id}`

  - Gets the users associated with the company with the given `id`
  - Add additional query parameters for pagination (if appropriate)
- `GET /group?id={id}`

  - Gets the group with the given `id`
- `GET /group/user?id={id}`

  - Gets the users associated with the group with the given `id`
  - Add additional query parameters for pagination (if appropriate)
- `GET /user?id={id}`

  - Gets the user with the given `id`
- `GET /user/group?id={id}`

  - Gets the groups associated with the user with the given `id`
  - Add additional query parameters for pagination (if appropriate)

---

## Add operations

- `POST /company`

  - Create a new company
  - Return new company `id` in response
- `POST /group`

  - Create a new group
  - Since every group must have an associated company, the associated company is a required field in JSON/XML body of post
  - Return new group `id` in response
  - Since every group must have an associated company, this also creates the company-group connection
- `POST /user`

  - Create a new new user
  - Since every user must have an associated company, the associated company is a required field in JSON/XML body of post
  - Return new user `id` in response
  - Since every user must have an associated company, this also creates the company-user connection
- `PUT /user/group?id={id}`

  - Associate a collection of groups to the user with the given `id`
- `PUT /group/user?id={id}`

  - Associate a collection of users to the group with the given `id`

---

## Remove operations

- `DELETE /company?id={id}`

  - Delete the company with the given `id`
  - Can either cascade delete to associated users and groups or block delete if any exist
- `DELETE /group?id={id}`

  - Delete the group with the given `id`
  - Also deletes the associated company-group connection
  - Does not delete any associated users - just deletes the user-group links
- `DELETE /user?id={id}`

  - Delete the user with the given `id`
  - Also deletes the associated company-user connection
  - Does not delete any associated groups - just deletes the user-group links
- `DELETE /user/group?id={id}`

  - Disassociate a collection of groups from the user with the given `id`
- `DELETE /group/user?id={id}`

  - Disassociate a collection of users from the group with the given `id`

---

If anything isn't clear just let me know in a comment and I can give clarification.

Comment: thanks, for your answer Timothy, but I have some questions: 1.Why are you using parameters rather than path variables(user/1/group/2)?  2."/user/group?id={id}"are you sure that is restful?

Comment: You could use path parameters instead, as you are suggesting for the id.  That would be equally valid.  I just prefer using only query parameters because they are a more uniform way of passing data to the requests. (Most http client libraries provide an easy mechanism for query parameters, but path parameters may require some string manipulation.  The "restful" specification only insists that every resource has a Uri - the query parameter is fine in that sense.